# Best Practices for Images in a Model with Castle ActiveRecord/MonoRail

Tags: castle-activerecord, castle-monorail

Our "user" model needs a small profile picture on it, and I'm not entirely sure how to handle it.  Of course we could just save it to a folder on disk and store the path/filename to the database, but I think I'd rather have it stored in the DB itself.

My first thought was to have a property on the model like this:

```
[Property] 
public byte[] ProfilePicture
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

But it sure feels like I'm going to have to go a LONG way to get it working this way -- getting a byte array from the database, then converting it to an image with some sort of handler.

Has anyone seen a good tutorial on how to handle this sort of thing?  It seems like it would be a common enough requirement that I'd find something MonoRail specific, but so far my searches have come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About storing images on database or files, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

If you decided to store it on DB, the most important thing is that you **don't** retrieve the `byte[]` every time you query for a User, that could be potentially a lot of data and a perf problem. To do that you could either store the image in another table or map the `byte[]` to another entity with the same table (assuming the user can have only one picture):

```
[ActiveRecord("users")]
public class UserWithoutPicture {
  [PrimaryKey]
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}
...
  [BelongsTo]
  public virtual UserProfilePicture ProfilePicture {get;set;}
}

[ActiveRecord("users")]
public class UserProfilePicture {
  [PrimaryKey]
  public virtual int Id {get;set;}

  [Property]
  public virtual byte[] Image {get;set;}
}
```

**This would have some funky behaviors though**. For example, for any given user, the `ProfilePicture` would never be null. You wouldn't really insert or delete `UserProfilePicture` since it's actually the user, instead you would always update. And you would incur an additional join, and you have to be aware of [SELECT N+1](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=select+n%2B1+nhibernate). That's just off the top of my head, **completely untested**.

Conclusion: storing images in another table is much more flexible.

If you want the convenience of dealing with an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) instead of raw `byte[]`, implement [`IUserType`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=nhibernate+iusertype). But remember that Image is an IDisposable, and it'll be *very hard* to dispose it at the right time.

Implementing a Monorail controller that returns an image is quite straightforward... just use `[ARFetch]` to get the `UserProfilePicture` by id and write to the Response stream with the appropriate content-type.